# Remove special char from phone number query %like%

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query in mysql:

```
foreach($keywords as $keywordKey => $keyword){
  $query = $query . " AND (id='".$keyword."' OR name LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR email LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR phone LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
}
$query = $query . " ORDER BY name";
$queryResult = mysql_query($query) or die('Error al ejecutar la busqueda de clientes con los parametros suministrados: '.mysql_error());;
```

`$keyworks` is an array with search bar's data. I want to remove the special chars from `phone LIKE '%".$keyword."%'`, because the users can be register using " . - ( ) " at phone number field and I am searching them with "clean" phone number (without special chars). How can I do It in mysql?

Comment: Well, if you haven't tried/searched anything it'll be harder.. What you want to do is [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) some characters before searching

Comment: Not really because I have to remove the special chars before of compare the query with $keywords. If I do the comparison after It, %like% return false always.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this outside of mysql and use php and some regex.

```
$phoneNumber = preg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $keyword);
```

That will replace all non numerical characters

Comment: No, I dont have to replace the special chars from $keywords, is over "phone" database column to compare It with $keywords.

Comment: What he's saying is that you need to format the data in the database, then removing special characters from the search query becomes easy. So use preg_replace on the data when inserting, and preg_replace on the keywords when searching. This way you don't deal with special characters at all, you just remove them from the equation entirely.